# biblatex style "bibtex key"

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I'd like the text that links to the references to be simply the bibtex key. So, with a bibtex entry like

```
@ARTICLE{Author1:2000:Topic,
  author      = {A. Author1 and B. Author2},
  title       = {Title},
  journal     = {Journal},
  year        = {2000},
  volume      = {1},
  pages       = {3--4}
}
```

I would like to have an in-text link `Author1:2000:Topic` and not a number style `[1]` or an author-year style `Author1 (2000)`.

The description of the **drftcite** package sounded as if it might have provided that functionality. But it does not work with the **biblatex** package:

```
! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'drftcite'.
```

The problem sounds to me rather simple, because nothing tricky has to be calculated. As I have to provide the bibtex key anyway, I could just write it into the text and use the \nocite command to have the respective entry in the reference list. But what I'm then obviously missing is the hyperlink from the citation to the reference list.

To provide a small working example that might be modified into an answer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{literature.bib}
@ARTICLE{Author1:2000:Topic,
  author      = {A. Author1 and B. Author2},
  title       = {Title},
  journal     = {Journal},
  year        = {2000},
  volume      = {1},
  pages       = {3--4}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literature}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\drftcite}[1]{\cite{#1}}

\begin{document}
\par This is shown in \drftcite{Author1:2000:Topic}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

After compilation with `pdflatex` and `bibtex`, I get a pdf with the following text:

```
    This is shown in Author1 and Author2, 2000.

References
Author1, A. and B. Author2 (2000). “Title”. In: Journal 1, pp. 3–4.
```

In this text, the first number `2000` is a hyperlink to the cited reference.

What I'd like to have, is a `\drftcite` command that instead of `Author1 and Author2, 2000` writes a hyperlink with the bibtex key `Author1:2000:Topic`.

Comment: Doesn't what `biblatex` show before you run BibTeX/Biber look very much like what you want?

Comment: After the first ``pdflatex`` run and before the ``biblatex`` run, the in-text citation looks (except for bold face and colour) like I want to have it, but there is no reference list yet and, thus, no link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `draft` citation style seems to cover what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{literature.bib}
@ARTICLE{Author1:2000:Topic,
  author      = {A. Author1 and B. Author2},
  title       = {Title},
  journal     = {Journal},
  year        = {2000},
  volume      = {1},
  pages       = {3--4}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle = draft, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literature}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\drftcite}[1]{\cite{#1}}

\begin{document}
\par This is shown in \drftcite{Author1:2000:Topic}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

where the citation here is a hyperlink.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! The ``draft`` option does it! And I like very much the possibility to determine ``bibstyle`` and ``citestyle`` separately.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want a `\drftcite` command that prints the `bibkey` and still want to be able to use the proper other citation commands, you can easily define `\drftcite` yourself.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\drftcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield[bibhyperref]{entrykey}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

That command can then be used just like any other cite command.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\drftcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield[bibhyperref]{entrykey}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\drftcite{cicero} and \drftcite{knuth:ct:a}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]