# Using reference name of cited source instead of number in text and bibliography

Tags: citing, biber

By default biber simply numbers the entries in my bibliography. How can I change the style to reflect the citation reference names I choose instead?

Example:

```
@book{myownreferencename,
  author    = {Abcd Somebody}, 
  title     = {some title},
  publisher = {some publisher},
  year      = 1990,
  volume    = 2
}
```

---

```
% no additional configuration of biblography
\bibliography{references}
% ...
\MakeBibliography
```

---

```
 Hey this is a source \cite{myownreference} that should show up.
```

---

Result: Hey this is a source[myownreference] that should show up.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Where does the command `\MakeBibliography` come from? Maybe your question gets easier to answer if you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: I think you are searching for this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173620/biblatex-style-bibtex-key/173647#173647  , if you change it to `backend=biber` it should work for you

Comment: Do you really want 'myownreference'  to show? That goes against the spirit of `biblatex`? Why don't you choose a name you can remember and let `biblatex` figure the label out itself.

Comment: Have a look at [Use BibTeX key as the cite key](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8428/35864) Your question looks like a duplicate of either that question or [biblatex style “bibtex key”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173620/35864). I will probably vote to close your question as a duplicate in due time, if you don't come back with any more questions or complaints.